# JQuery keyup and change event trigged by clicking elsewhere on the page

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a search form that includes dropdowns and an `<input type="text">` element.  I wanted to perform an AJAX request based on whether a selection is made from the dropdown OR something is typed in the field.

I have used this script to accomplish this -

```
$('#searchform').on('keyup change', function() {
      //DO THE AJAX SEARCH
}
```

Everything works fine, except the event is triggered by clicking anywhere on the page after the form is used, as I imagine it is viewed as a 'change.'

So, for example, I append some search results to an HTML div, and then when a user goes to click on the result, the 'form' change event is triggered and it attempts to perform the function once again.  It doesn't change the results, but it still produces an undesirable effect.

Is there a way I can make the AJAX request triggered by either a dropdown selection or typing in an input field, but have it ignore the request if the change is not ON the `#searchform` element?

Comment: when you say the event is triggered when clicking anywhere on the page, is that because the input was focused and removing focus triggers a change event? if so then you may want to define two separate handlers, one for the input keyup and one for the select change

Comment: yea, that's what I meant.  I thought about setting up two different handlers initially, but I tried this route at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one other option.  You could bind the ajax request to the form submit and then trigger the submit with the other events.  Might be overkill for your situation, but adds in some flexibility if you need different form elements to behave differently

```
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Ajax here
});

$('#searchform input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#searchform').trigger('submit');
});

$('#searchform select').on('change', function() {
    $('#searchform').trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: This ended up being my solution.  Other suggestions worked great except the input 'change' event still triggered the function regardless of how I tried to prevent it.  I ended up splitting up the event handlers.  Kudos on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#searchform').on('keyup change', function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).hasClass('mySpecialInputClass') {
          // execute your code
      }
}
```

`e.target` is the element that initiated the event. There are other properties of the event object you may find useful.

Comment: You could also include the selector in the .on options. (i.e., .on('keyup change', '.class1 .class2', function() { ...

Comment: Wow, really appreciate the help fellas!  @spaceman817 do you want to provide as an answer so I can mark?

Comment: Nah, that's okay. Brad M has a good answer, I was just suggesting a way you could simplify it.

Comment: But does this really fix the issue? it will still bind to the change event on the input

Comment: That's true. With my suggestion it would only bind to the elements that you specify in the .on options. I'll post an updated answer..

Comment: @spaceman817 That is 50% true for this case. You can't technically bind the `keyup` event to a specific element(with a class); jQuery just internally checks if the `event.target` has that class. The `change` event however can be bound to a specific element.

Answer (score 1):

This will bind the **keyup** and **change** events to the class selectors you place in the .on options (in this case, only elements with class1 and class2 would be affected).

```
$('#searchform').on('keyup change', '.class1 .class2', function() {
      // execute your code
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.` before the class name. And to improve this even more, since you are giving unique classes, you don't need to include the searchform id. `$('.class1 .class2').on('keyup change', function() {
      /* execute your code */
}`

Comment: This works well, except @koala_dev is right, it does still bind to the change of the input.  Works great for the drop downs, but I think ponysmith's answer is now better, where I should separate them by events.